# Why is my if statement an error?

Tags: java, if-statement, timer

This code is supposed to stop an object from passing through it, ans if an object hits it, make it so it has to wait 1 second before it can be interacted with again. I thought the best place to but the timer would be after the keylistener, but when I tried to put an if statement down, it just came up as an error, even though it seems to be complete.

What can I do to fix this, and is there a better way to do this?

I put the problem statement towards the middle, and added comment lines at the start and end of the if statement. Thank you for your help.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Imject {

int x = 30;
int y = 30;
int xa = 0;
int ya = 0;
private CrcGame Game;

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)
        if (collision()){
            ya = 0;
            y =- y;
        }
        else {ya = 1;
        }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
        if (collision()){
            ya = 0;
        }
        else {ya = -1;
        }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        if (collision()){
            xa = 0;
        }
        else {xa = 1;
        }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        if (collision()){
            xa = 0;
        }
        else {xa = -1;
        }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    ya = 0;
    xa = 0;
}

//Starts
if (collision()){

}
//Ends

void move() {
    if (x + xa > 0)
        x = x + xa;
    if (y + ya > 0)
        y = y + ya;
}

public Imject(CrcGame Game) {
    this.Game= Game;
}

private boolean collision() {
    return Game.player.getBounds().intersects(getBounds());
}

public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 20);
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, 100, 20);
}
```

}

Comment: when do you expect that statement to be executed?

Comment: You do realize that `if` statements cannot be sitting in the middle of a class?

Comment: Where is the open and close curly braces of every if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem if statement isn't in a function, it's just sitting in the class. You need to move it into one of your methods. Try combining your move function and your collision check.

```
void move() {
    if (x + xa > 0)
        x = x + xa;
    if (y + ya > 0)
        y = y + ya;
    }
    if (collision()){

    }
}
```

Comment: may be my question was not clear: which `if` statement are you referring to by the term "outside if"?

Comment: an `if ... else ...` block is a single statement. It does not need enclosing brackets. Plus, the OP is indicating the position of the issue with comments in the code. At this place there is no nested ifs.

Comment: if (collision()) is not in a method, at least not that I can tell. @AndrewL.